# Pika and RabbitMQ - create a queue on a specific node

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I've got a rabbitmq cluster with two nodes. I'd like to create some queues to be hosted on node1, and other queues hosted on node2.

Even when I set the host in ConnectionParameters to node2, the queue will still end up created on node1.

Programmatically, I'm not sure how to use pika to specify the node I'd like a queue created on. There's no such parameter in `queue_declare`, and passing in the argument like this doesn't seem to work:

```
channel.queue_declare(queue="whereami", durable=True, exclusive=False, auto_delete=False, callback=on_queue_declared, arguments= {'node':'rabbit@node1'})
```

Is there any interface for specifying the hosting node? Is there another way to handle this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find any arguments to specify on which node in cluster queue will be created, but I have a walk around to this. Assume that you have two nodes in cluster rabbit@node1 and rabbit@node2, you can simply specify:

```
arguments["x-ha-policy"] = "nodes"
arguments["x-ha-policy-params"] = 'rabbit@node1'
```

This one will create queue that will residue only on node1.

Answer (score 0):

Clusters are usually defined on different hosts, or with different ports on the same host ([see docs for more on this](http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html)).

One can define both a host and a port number as part of the `pika.connection.ConnectionParameters`.

Comment: This doesn't work. It'll still connect to the cluster as a whole and create the host on the master. Like, if I have node1 and node2 in a cluster and attach to node2 in ConnectionParameters, it'll still create the queue on node1. There's got to be something in the queue_declare itself.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on your cluster setup?  

1.  Are these nodes on separate physical machines or on the same machine with different ports?   
2.  Are they configured for high availability, either with an active/active or an active/passive setup?

Comment: Sure! They're on two separate physical machines, and are both disk nodes. They aren't configured for high availability. Basically, two distinct business groups use the two different nodes. They're clustered to allow them to share the same exchanges. Keeping their queues separated means that if one group's program stops acking messages, it only affects that group when the queue fills up and eats disk space.